# How to check if user email verified?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I want to verify the user еmail, for this I send the verification link, follow it, and expect the isEmailVerified property to change its value to true, but this does not happen (even if I reopen the application). The property changes its value to true only if I log out and log in again.

What is the explanation for this behavior? How to check a user email for verification without leaving account?

*ContentView.swift:*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if (self.session.session != nil) {
                VStack{
                    Text("Logged In As \(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email ?? "")")
                    Text("\(String(self.session.session!.isEmailVerified!))")
//This also print false:
//Text("\(String((Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)!))")

                    Button(action: {Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
                        // ...
                    }}){
                        Text("Verify email")
                    }
                    Button(action: {session.signOut()}){
                        Text("Sign Out")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                SignInView()
            }
            
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            session.listen()
        })
    }
}
```

*SessionStore.swift:*

```
class SessionStore : ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    @Published var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listen () {
        // monitor authentication changes using firebase
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                // if we have a user, create a new user model
                print("Got user: \(user)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.session = User(
                        uid: user.uid,
                        displayName: user.displayName,
                        email: user.email,
                        isEmailVerified: user.isEmailVerified
                    )
                }
            } else {
                // if we don't have a user, set our session to nil
                self.session = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signUp(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback
    ) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }
    func signIn(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }
    
    func signOut () -> Bool {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.session = nil
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show code of `SessionStore` and `Session`? Where is `isEmailVerified` updated, or supposed to be updated?

Comment: @Asperi yes, I have updated question. Isn't isEmailVerified updated in listen method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you need to refresh user object:

`Auth.auth()?.currentUser.reload()`

Then you can check for any updated data